# Connection to the server was unsuccessful

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I can't run Android APK of my ionic apps on my tablets (Android version 4.4), I get the connection unsuccessful error. I have no idea why, it happens even if I start a ionic project from scratch and run the apk without modifying anything in the project. Weird thing is..I can run it on my Xperia celphone and also if I emulate a Nexus 9 tablet with android studio the Apk also works. How can I fix this? maybe build the apk with older android api? is there a way of doing this, or isn't this related?

Already tried setting loadUrlTimeoutValue to a high number, makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah finally got it FFS, had to add cordova crosswalk plugin to make it work. Followed this > https://github.com/codyteng/ionic2-android-crosswalk

ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

ionic platform add android

ionic run android